# Динамическое изменение размеров View в Android

Tags: android, view

С api 25 проблем нет, но с api 17 элементы просто не реагирует на setLayoutParams,setWidth и так далее. Что нужно сделать в таком случае?

---

Да простой код - в эмуляторе с api 25 работает, с api 17 не работает.

```
FrameLayout ht1 = (FrameLayout) ty.getChildAt(c);
TextView tv = (TextView) ht1.getChildAt(0);
tv.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(len,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Также не работает setWith и так далее, то есть параметры изменяются, но элемент заново не прорисовывается. Помню, что делал что-то с методом mesure, вроде работало, но сейчас уже  не помню как это делается в деталях.

Comment: попробуйте заменить `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` на `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`

Comment: Поменял, ничего не изменилось, только при повороте экрана( ловится событие)  вылетает ошибка.  android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams

Comment: LayoutParams lp = tv.getLayoutParams(); lp.width = len; tv.requestLayout(); а если так?

Comment: Все по старому , разве что ошибка не вылетает при повороте экрана. Схема примерно такова- смена страниц приложения осуществляется с помощью inflateLayout(XML- макетов), а не с помощью создания новых активностей. На проблемной странице элементы добавляются динамически, при этом размер одного элемента подстраивается под размер другого. Также ловится событие поворот экрана - и идет та же подстройка элементов. Активность не перегружается при повороте экрана(отключил). Такая схема хорошо работает с api 25, но с api 17 -нет- то есть попытка изменять размеры динамически не проходит.

Comment: К схеме претензий нет, сам такой пользуюсь. Последнее, что могу предложить - засунуть этот фрагмент кода в tv.post() например.

Comment: заработало в api 17. Думаю и с 25 проблем не будет. Спасибо , выручили. 1.5 дня мучился с этой проблемой.